# Query on foreign work experience

Tags: canada, immigration, resident-permit

As per new point system for Canada, Does foreign work experience does not add any value?

As mentioned `With Canadian work experience and foreign work experience` in this [link](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/express-entry/grid-crs.asp), Do we require 1 year Canada experience for the same?

Comment: Wow, is that confusing compared to the prior version.

Comment: IELTS score is being given more weightage in  express entry

Comment: I don't think so. There is a foreign work experience section well down the page. See Section C. I *think* you can substitute a year of Canadian work experience for meeting the language requirement as you can score 50 points for either (1. language skills plus foreign work or 2. Canadian work plus foreign work).

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem to be true from the same link you posted if you look for [Foreign Work Experience with Good Language Proficiency](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/express-entry/grid-crs.asp) you can find the information on the subject.

**I didn't copy the text since it's a table format**